# Why does Yeoman build without /styles/fonts?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

After running `grunt build` I'm left with no `fonts` directory inside `dist/styles`.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I have in the `Gruntfile.js`:

> ```
>     compass: {
>         options: {
>             sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
>             cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
>             imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/../images',
>             javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
>             fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/../styles/fonts',
>             importPath: 'app/bower_components',
>             relativeAssets: true,
>         },
>         dist: {
>             options: {
>                 imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
>                 fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/../styles/fonts'
>             }
>         },
>         server: {
>             options: {
>                 debugInfo: true
>             }
>         }
>     },
> ```

Comment: Not sure of your project layout, but should `fontsDir` under `dist` be  `yeoman.dist` instead of `yeoman.app`?

Comment: Tried that, still no fonts directory. The dist.options is actually initially empty. This was just me, trying stuff out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `compass` task isn't responsible for copying fonts over from `app` to `dist`. This is instead handled by the `copy` task, which usually looks like this:

```
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        'bower_components/**/*',
        'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
        'styles/fonts/*' // <-- Where fonts are copied.
      ]
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/images',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      src: [
        'generated/*'
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: aaaaaaaand it works. :}  Is there a reason it's not initially set?

Comment: Most generators have this out of the box. Which one did you use?

Comment: Oddly enough, the Backbone Generator.

Comment: I didn't know what wrong i was doing till i found this solution